# How to rename title column in Document Library using code?

Tags: development, column, rename

Everybody loves renaming columns. The title column is a favorite of mine and I can't seem to rename it via code:

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");
Guid guid = new Guid("fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247"); //Title column
SPField field = list.Fields[guid];
field.Title = "Testing";
field.Update();
list.Update();
```

The **title** column always stays the title column. Of course I don't want to rename the `InternalName` or anything crazy, but since you can't remove the column it would be nice if it actually had a meaningful name in my SP context.

So the question in short: **How to rename the title column/field in a document library using code (that means C# - not XML)?"**

PS: Of course it works via the UI. Go to document library settings > Columns > Title and you can change the name to your liking (this is updated on all views then)

---

Further investigation shows that it doesn't even work with the `SchemaXML`:

```
string schema = field.SchemaXML;
schema.Replace("Title", "NewNameHere");
field.SchemaXml = schema;
field.Update();
list.Update();
```

Still the field's display name is "Title.

---

More testing code for you (again this doesn't change anything for me):

```
Guid listGuid = web.Lists.Add("TestListNow", "", SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
SPList list = web.Lists[listGuid];

SPField field = list.Fields[new Guid("fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247")];
field.Title = "FieldTitle";
field.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture(new CultureInfo(1031), "Culture1031");
field.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture(new CultureInfo(1033), "Culture1033");
field.TitleResource.Update();
field.Update();
list.Update();
```

The title field stays "Titel" (German title). When going in the same list via the UI I can change the column name...

---

*Working Code:*

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://myurl.com"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.lists.TryGetList("TestList");
        SPField field = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title");
        field.Title = "NewTitle";
        field.Update();
        field.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture(new CultureInfo(1031), "NewTitle");
        field.TitleResource.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are u able to fix this issue as I am also encountrying the , the title of coulumn changes in second time code execution and that to with changed name. Please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That could be due to localization. In that case, you should also set [TitleResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.titleresource.aspx) property:

```
field.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture(new CultureInfo(1033), "My title");
```

Actually, I've done renaming of Title plenty of times, and I can't see any difficulties there. Your SchemaXml approach probably didn't work for the same localization reason.

By the way, Title column can be easily deleted, just set AllowDeletion property to false before deleting it: although, it is not recommended, because you will lose some logging features and standard workflows functionality.

Comment: Localization is a very good Idea. I tried what you suggested with German locale (SP is German installed) as well as 1033. I also did a `field.TitleResource.Update()` - all to no avail. When looking at he Schema there isn't anything suggesting localization, the field has the attributes: `Type, Name, ShowInNewForm, DisplayName, Sealed, SourceID, StaticName, ColName`. In the end it is just a plain old Doclib with some custom fields added.

Comment: according to my working code: after setting TitleResource and `field.TitleResource.Update()` I have also a call to `field.Update()` - have you tried this?

Comment: To represent localized field schema, they have separated property, SchemaWithResourceTokens - but this property is readonly. What you can try with SchemaXml, is setting it in different locales contexts, or passing resource tokens into it. But actually I haven't dealed with this approach, because for me SetValueForUICulture method works like a charm.

Comment: I got to work now! But **only** when getting the field via `.GetFieldByInternalName("Title")`. Yes I pretty much update everything. Last weird behavior: The name change only applies after the *second* time I run the code. E.g. I change the title to "FirstTitle" --> "Titel" remains. I run the code a second time, now using "SecondTitle" --> column is renamed to "FirstTitle". Now I run the code a third time "ThirdTitle" --> "SecondTitle" is applied...

Comment: hmmm.. could you try this sequence: `field.Title = 'something';`, then `field.Update();`, then `field.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture(...);`, and finally, `field.TitleResource.Update();`. Exactly this sequence, no any other updates please.

Comment: Same result - I posted the code above. I run it in a simple Test Console Application, the second time I run the code the title gets updated to what I had in the first run. Also tried `iisreset` in between - didn't help.

Comment: Fun fact: When I run the code just as it is a second time (e.g. `field.Title = "NewTitle"`) the title is **not** updated. When I change the title (e.g. `field.Title = "AnotherTitle"`) during the second run of the console app - the change of the first run is applied. Weird!

Answer (score 4):

I only tried this in PowerShell, where I can confirm that SetValueForUICulture() doesn't persist the value (or rather it looks like it is set in the database, but GetValueForUICulture() retrieves the old value even though the internal property ResxBased is set to false).

What worked for me was to *not* use SetValueForUICulture() but instead set the title property after switching the CurrentUIThread culture:

```
[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = "da-DK"
$title = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title")
$title.Title = "My Danish Title"
$title.Update($true) #true=pushChangesToList
```

This will effectively update title field, and all the related Title "shadow fields".

I also saw it working if I assigned TitleResource to a variable, and first updated that, and *then* the title directly:

```
$tr = $title.TitleResource
$tr.SetValueForUiCulture($web.UICulture,"My Title")
$tr.Update()

$title.Title = "My Title"
$title.Update($true)
```

which really doesnt make much sense. I guess some MUI flag gets triggered by SetValueForUiCulture, but SPUserRessource.Update() seems rather buggy!

Comment: Very good research.

Comment: This worked for me, too. Additionally you could "wrap" the change of `CurrentUICulture` in a nice function as was done here: https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/getting-and-setting-language-dependent-field-titles-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit different. I wrote a blogpost about it here:
http://carolinepoint.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/add-a-multilingual-field-to-sharepoint-through-code/

So in short:
You want to set the Thread.Current.CurrentUICulture to the culture of the language you which to change. Then change them with field.TitleResource.SetValueForCulture or field.DescriptionResource.SetValueForCulture and call the field.TitleResource.Update() or the field.DescriptionResource.Update()

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. [moderator]

Answer (score 0):

None of the code above worked for me (SP Foundation 2013). I did it like this:

```
$webUrl = "http://localhost:80"
$newTitle = "New Title for the field"

$w = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$ct = $w.ContentTypes["My Content Type Name"]
$fl = $ct.FieldLinks["MyColumn"]
$fl.DisplayName = $newTitle
$ct.Update($true)

$w.Dispose()
```

Comment: This question was specifically about the *Title* column not about just any column `$fl = $ct.FieldLinks["MyColumn"]`.

Comment: You right, it's more generic approach for custom column. Thought it might be useful for some1(like me), that was redirected here from Google's "rename field title" request.