# CSOM - How to rename a Document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, csom

Is there a way in CSOM wherein I can rename document library using CSOM like we do in SPD(renaming the root folder)?

I tried several ways e.g update`Title`,`FileLeafRef`. Also tried to rename a folder etc but nothing seems to work.

I would like to know if is this possible at all?

Comment: You can get some reference from here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/how-to-rename-title-column-in-document-library-using-code

Answer (score 0):

Please reference https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/137221/75930

It seems to do what you are asking in SharePoint 2013, you should use the Folder.MoveTo method to create a copy under a new name, and then delete the old.